# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pip, jupyter-notebook

Имею Win7_64, Python 3.7.0, Selenium 3.141.0( pip3 freeze показывает, что установлен), ChromeDriver 2.45, Chrome 71, pip3 check возвращает "no broken requirements found", пытаюсь в Jupiter использовать Selenium - получаю:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\user\\chromedriver_win32')
driver.get("http://www.google.com")

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-ff99d40ae1f5> in <module>()
----> 1 from selenium import webdriver
      2 driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\user\\chromedriver_win32')
      3 driver.get("http://www.google.com")
      4 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Помогите разобраться, что надо еще сделать, чтоб использовать Selenium.

Comment: Предполагаю, что Jupiter использует другой питон

Comment: я их устанавливал одновременно

Comment: Честно, с юпитером не работал, поэтому тут могу только предполагать по тому, что вы рассказали и по той ошибке

Comment: Если при установки Юпитера вы создавали виртуальное окружение Питона, то именно туда вы и должны устанавливать пакеты Питона.

Comment: при установке Юпитера я не создавал  виртуального окружения, и, кроме того, к примеру, requests, согласно pip3 freeze, в глобальном окружении, и при этом импортируется в Юпитер

Comment: Потому что `requests` стандартная библиотека Python 3. А при обычном создании виртуального окружения в него копируются **_все стандартные_** бибилотеки. Поэтому `requests` у вас есть, а `selenium` нет.

Comment: Какой IDLE вы пользуетесь? Даже если при установке Юпитера вы обошли шаг с созданием виртуального окружения, вы могли (случайно/не заметить) создать его когда создавали новый проект в IDLE.

Comment: В качестве среды я пользуюсь Юпитером. Для создания виртуального окружения, мне казалось, необходим vertualenv, который я не устанавливал и которого, согласно pip freeze, нет в глобальном окружении.

Comment: к примеру в случае с PyCharm vertualenv поставляется внутри IDE, поэтому при создании виртуального окружения силами IDE вам не требуется установка vertualenv в хост-окружение. Поэтому может получится ситуация (как у меня), что новые виртуальные окружения есть, а библиотеки vertualenv в хосте нет. Именно поэтому наличие/отсутствие vertualenv в оригинальном Питоне не значит ничего.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы создали виртуальное окружение в PyCharm (изначально PyCharm его создает).
Тогда решением для установки Selenium:

File -> Settings... -> Project: Python -> Project Interpreted -> (по умолчанию будет выбрано созданное виртуальное окружение) -> Нажать "+" с правой стороны окна -> Ввести "Selenium" в строку поиска -> Install Package